# Background Worker In Winforms Not Updating TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I am attempting to use a Background Worker in order to add a Cancel button to my winform.

I have added the below syntax, but the textbox is never updated with any progress as it was before I tried to implement the background worker.

```
public Form1()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
    {
        string resourceName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
        string resource = Array.Find(this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames(), element => element.EndsWith(resourceName));

        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
        {
            Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
        }
    };
    InitializeComponent(); 
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;  
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}
private void btnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

        //Iterating the array
        foreach (string s in sxc)
        {
            txt_ProgressDetails.Visible = true;
            AppendTextBoxLine("Getting Data For " + s);

            //Put data into DataTable
            PopulateDT(s);
        }

        //If the cancel button was pressed
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
}

    private void AppendTextBoxLine(string statusMessage)
    {
        if (txt_ProgressDetails.Text.Length > 0)
            txt_ProgressDetails.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        txt_ProgressDetails.AppendText(statusMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks a little flaky. What's the point of `if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)` being checked **after** the loop? It's too late then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Do_Work event of BackgroundWorker runs in a non-STA thread and you can't update UI from there. You can rewrite your code to update UI elements from the thread that created them with `InvokeRequred` and `Invoke` method.

Add this to your Form:

```
delegate void UpdateUICallback(string statusMessage);
```

And Change your `AppendTextBoxLine` method to this:

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    UpdateUICallback d = new UpdateUICallback(AppendTextBoxLine);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] {statusMessage});
}
else
{
    if (txt_ProgressDetails.Text.Length > 0)
            txt_ProgressDetails.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    txt_ProgressDetails.AppendText(statusMessage);
}
```

so your code will look like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
    {
        string resourceName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
        string resource = Array.Find(this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames(), element => element.EndsWith(resourceName));

        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
        {
            Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
        }
    };
    InitializeComponent(); 
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;  
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}
private void btnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

        //Iterating the array
        foreach (string s in sxc)
        {
            txt_ProgressDetails.Visible = true;
            AppendTextBoxLine("Getting Data For " + s);

            //Put data into DataTable
            PopulateDT(s);
        }

        //If the cancel button was pressed
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
}

delegate void UpdateUICallback(string statusMessage);
private void AppendTextBoxLine(string statusMessage)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        UpdateUICallback d = new UpdateUICallback(AppendTextBoxLine);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] {statusMessage});
    }
    else
    {
        if (txt_ProgressDetails.Text.Length > 0)
                txt_ProgressDetails.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        txt_ProgressDetails.AppendText(statusMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i add delegate voice UpdateUICallback(); to my Form1() I get multiple compile errors

Comment: Why? What Compile errors? I edited the answer so the method can take one string argument as your previous code

Comment: I Edited the answer to improve it and at the same time answer this question